# proving whether a function is one-to-one/onto

Tags: functions, proof-writing

```
1) f(n) = 2n + 1 from set of integers to set of integers
2) f(n) = 2[n/2] from set of integers to set of integers   [] is floor
```

Could someone demonstrate how I would prove whether these are one-to-one and/or onto?

For example, on the first one:

f(n) = 2n+1

I can look at it and try some numbers: (0,1), (1,3), (2,5)...

every A has a unique B it looks like, so it is one-to-one (injective)

it does not look like every B has at least one A because we skip 2, 4, etc. so it is not onto (surjective)

but how would i write a proof for this?

Answer (score 1):

Tidus,

To show that a function is injective, you need to show that if two points $x$ and $y$ get mapped to the same point, i.e. $f(x)=f(y)$, then we must have $x=y$. For the first function $f(n)=2n+1$, this is quite straight forward since if we have two integers $n,m$ such that $f(n)=f(m)$, this means that $2n+1=2m+1\Rightarrow n=m$.

To show that it is surjective, we must show that for every $n$, we can find another integer $m$ such that $f(m)=n$. However, note that the set $Im(f)=\{f(n)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}=\{2n+1\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is precisely equal to the set of odd integers. Therefore, $f$ is not onto (nothing maps to even integers).

I will leave the second function to you as an easy exercise!

Answer (score 0):

The formal definition of one-to-one is that for any x and y, f(x) = f(y) implies that x = y. So for f(n) = 2n+1, let's suppose that for some m and n, f(m) = f(n). Then 2m+1 = 2n+1, and with a bit of algebra m = n showing that it is one-to-one.

For f(n) = 2[n/2] (where I assume [] is either a round, ceiling or floor function), if you can show that there are two values, m and n, that are distinct but produce the same value for f(), then that's enough to prove that it is not one-to-one.

For onto, you need to show that all possible values of the codomain are possible values of f, or to prove that it's not onto you need to show that there are values in the codomain that cannot be values of f. You have the right feeling for this for (a), and I would put that as something like "Suppose that f(n) is onto. Then for all x in the integers, there exists an integer n such that f(n) = x. Let x = 2. Then 2n + 1 = 2 => n = -1/2, which is not in the integers, so there is no such n. By contradiction, f(n) is not onto." For (b) I'll give you the hint that it is onto, and so the hard part will be proving so (possibly by showing that for any x in the integers you can always provide an n such that f(n) = x).

Comment: (b) is a floor function yeah, so how is that onto?

so f(n) = 2[n/2], we get: 
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
(4, 4)
(5, 4) 

it skips the odd integers, so every B does not have at least one A. so that's not onto?

Comment: Sounds right to me. If it were just f(n) = [n/2], though, then you'd have an onto function.